# Should "Data" tag be renamed to include context to avoid ambiguity?

Tags: tags, retagging, discussion

Should [data](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data) tag be renamed to include context to avoid ambiguity?

Since the tags are all lower-case, it's hard to tell whether the tag pertains to Lt. Commander Data of Star Trek:TNG, or to a noun "data".

Perhaps the tag should be named something like "data(st:tng)" or "lt-commander-data"?

Question 1: Should it be renamed at all?

Question 2: If so, what's a good new name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I agree. [I had the same concern for Q](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1563/why-is-there-a-voldemort-tag-is-there-a-criteria-for-character-tags/1566#1566), whose tag is now [star-trek-q](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-q). Given the apparent support, and that it's reversible, I've renamed [data](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data) to [star-trek-data](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-data) (moderators can rename a tag without editing questions).

Comment: What if I have a question about the data that Star Trek provides? IE, Star Trek Data?

Comment: @OghmaOsiris You're really clutching at straws… but that's plain [tag:star-trek] anyway.