# Tagging Middle-earth

Tags: discussion, tags

We have [lord-of-the-rings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings), [the-hobbit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hobbit), [silmarillion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/silmarillion), [tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien), [rings-of-power](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rings-of-power), and [middle-earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-earth). And they're just the ones I've noticed. I'm inclined to think that anyone interested in any of these will be interested in all of them, so the tags should all be merged into [middle-earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-earth). Am I completely wrong?

Comment: LOTR isn't my fandom (well, a bit), but from the POV of someone whose fandom *does* have a fair share of tags, I don't think the issue is the existence of the individual tags. I think the issue is some users don't use tags judiciously. It's a bit unnecessary to add 8 tags to a question or whatever. But *The Hobbit* isn't *The Silmarillion* and J.R.R. Tolkien isn't Middle Earth, and if I want to search for posts about Tolkien, I don't want to pull up every single post that's ever been written on anything related to LOTR or *The Hobbit* or *The Silmarillion*. Know what I mean? :)

Comment: Just to clarify, `rings-of-power` as originally conceieved was NOT meant to be Tolkien specific, they can (and do) include other powerful rings (e.g. Green Lantern ones). Wiki for the tag makes it clear. Majority of questions are from LOTR, but not all.

Comment: @DVK - I can't say I like that idea. I've always thought tags should have a single subject matter - for example, I wouldn't combine star trek & doctor who's doctors into [the-doctor] - they're both very different subject areas

Comment: @Robotnik - there's a difference between identical word (doctor) and identical **concept** (ring granting a wearer power)

Comment: @DVK - at the end of the day it should be about expertise. Someone following this tag isn't going to be an expert in all of LOTR ringlore, Green Lantern ringlore, Captain planet ringlore, and any other ringlore from any other work, nor are they going to want Green lantern etc popping up when looking for questions on LOTR ringlore (or vice versa).

Answer (score 9):

*The Lord of the Rings*, *The Hobbit*, and *The Silmarillion* are all separate works, so merging them would not be desirable. The other tags are meant to specify particular areas of Tolkien's legendarium. Someone wanting to learn more about the Rings for instance can look at that particular tag. The same goes for Middle Earth or for Tolkien himself. Therefore I don't think that any of the tags you specified should be merged...(and if they were to be merged a more apt name would be something like [tolkiens-legendarium](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkiens-legendarium))

Comment: I generally prefer fewer tags over more, but I agree with your answer.  I don't love the idea of [tag:rings-of-power], but I would imagine it is really hard to search for questions specifically on the rings without getting mixed up with general [tag:lord-of-the-rings] questions, so it does make sense.

Comment: @Beofett Definitely agree with less tags is more. [tag:rings-of-power] seems to be necessary as you say, since if you search "rings" with LOTR, you inevitably don't gain any specificity.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with merging all the tags, but I agree that they are used inconsistently and we should do some cleanup.

[tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien) is necessary because not everything Tolkien wrote is set in Middle-Earth.

When it comes to Middle-Earth, I think we have broadly three audiences:

1. People who've seen the Peter Jackson movies and are mostly interested in the movies and how they relate to the book.
2. People who've seen Tolkien's influence (for example, from playing D&D), and might have read *The Hobbit*, *Lord of the Rings* and just maybe the *Silmarillion*.
3. People who're interested in Middle-Earth minutiae, but don't know all of Christopher's publications by heart yet.

A good tagging system would help people in category 1 and 2 quickly find the questions they are interested in. Here, [lord-of-the-rings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings) and [the-hobbit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hobbit) will appeal to audiences 1 and 2, but [middle-earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-earth) is likely to come as too detailed. Audience 1 will likely ignore [silmarillion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/silmarillion).

I'm not convinced we need [rings-of-power](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rings-of-power) or [akallabeth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/akallabeth), or [gandalf](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gandalf), [saruman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saruman), [sauron](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sauron), ... (See the related discussions on character tags, such as [the latest one](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2463/do-we-need-an-amy-pond-tag).) In fact, I've gone ahead and merged [akallabeth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/akallabeth) into [silmarillion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/silmarillion).

We should make a complete list of Tolkien-related tags (I don't have the time just now) and figure out how they're currently used and whether we want that to continue.

Once we as a community reach a decision, we should edit the relevant tag wikis and get at least most of the questions tagged the way we want them.

Answer (score 1):

Could we merge [the-one-ring](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-one-ring) into [rings-of-power](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rings-of-power) please?  They go to the same posts because of the way the One Ring is magically linked to the Rings of Power, and the two tags just take up precious space of the limit of 5 tags.

Comment: An answer on a downvoted question isn't going to get much attention, I'm afraid. I'd suggest adding a new question.