# Deathly Hallows tag: Book or Objects?

Tags: discussion

The 'Deathly-Hallows' tag currently exists and seems to be used often to refer to the Book (*[Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Deathly_Hallows)*). But when I first saw it, I initially thought that it was meant for the **[Deathly Hallows](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Deathly_Hallows)** objects (The elder Wand, The Invisibility Cloak and The Resurrection Stone).

**Which is correct?**

Both?

My question is unfortunately not answered here:  [Harry Potter tag cleanup](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3560/harry-potter-tag-cleanup)

Comment: WHat does the tag Wiki say?

Comment: @DVK It says that I forgot to check it first and now I feel like an idiot for posting a pointless question... :)

Comment: I think several book-specific tags got burninated in the HP tag cleanup; by the same token, we probably shouldn’t use DH to describe anything except the objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tag wiki for the [deathly-hallows](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deathly-hallows) tag says:

> Three magical objects in the Harry Potter universe that together give the owner mastery over death. Specifically, they are the Elder Wand, Resurrection Stone and Cloak of Invisibility. 
> *https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/deathly-hallows/info*

**Therefore, the tag relates to the [Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magical_objects_in_Harry_Potter#Deathly_Hallows) and not the Book/Movies.**

Comment: Additionally: therefore, I must learn to read the tag-wikis.