# How should we tag Rick Riordan's works?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've just taken a look through the tags that we use for the works of Rick Riordan. For those unfamiliar, there are different series, all of them dealing with mythological gods and monsters in the world today, all of them at least nominally set in the same universe.

Each of the different series at the moment has its own tag:

- [percy-jackson](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/percy-jackson)<sup>1</sup>
- [heroes-of-olympus](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-of-olympus)<sup>2</sup>
- [the-kane-chronicles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-kane-chronicles)<sup>3</sup>
- [magnus-chase](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magnus-chase)<sup>4</sup>
- [the-trials-of-apollo](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-trials-of-apollo)<sup>5</sup>

Also, we have a [rick-riordan](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rick-riordan) tag, but since we only use author tags for questions *about the author*...<sup>6</sup>

These are all set in the same universe<sup>3</sup>. I'd like a way to keep track of all new questions about this universe, without watching 6 different tags for the same universe - for now, I can [search](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/percy-jackson+or+heroes-of-olympus+or+the-kane-chronicles+or+rick-riordan+or+magnus-chase+or+the-trials-of-apollo?sort=newest&pageSize=50) for questions with any of those tags, but it's... slightly clunky. How should we tag this universe as a whole?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>This is also being used as a sort of general universe tag for the Greek storyline - it's been seen on *Percy Jackson & the Olympians* questions, *The Heroes of Olympus* questions, and *The Trials of Apollo* questions.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup>(Why don't we have the 'the' here? Ugh...)</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup>While *The Kane Chronicles* is a *little* less firmly set in the same universe, it's got [enough clues](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/659/58) and some shared characters that it's in the same universe... plus 3 crossover stories ;)</sub>

<sub><sup>4</sup>[magnus-chase-and-the-gods-of-asgard](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magnus-chase-and-the-gods-of-asgard) fits in the tag character limit, surely that's a better name that can be used...</sub>

<sub><sup>5</sup>Okay, there's only one question tagged with this and I created the tag today. I plead guilty.</sub>

<sub><sup>6</sup>Not that we have such a great track record of *keeping* with that policy...</sub>

Comment: [*I've removed the author tag because we only use them for questions about the author...*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174591/what-does-the-cuckoo-represent#comment469574_174591) Speak for yourself ;)

Comment: @Edlothiad - sure, but check out, say, the [`jk-rowling`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jk-rowling) tag, and, indeed, the [`rick-riordan`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rick-riordan) tag mentioned in the question.

Comment: I try to fix the `jk-rowling`s when I see them, but at least I now have something to do at work. I didn't know what a `rick-riordan` was until 7 minutes ago, may excuse me missing those, but we have a pretty good track record of keeping up with that policy.

Answer (score 6):

### As per [most of our](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4861/68872) agreed consensuses [on the matter](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7924/68872) this should have a universe tag.

While we're reasonably inconsistent with our use of individual work tags, we normally accept not adding them when they're part of a series, so we don't really need any more specific work tags for the series. This may become a thing we need to readdress in the future but that can come when we've had a good, long, hard think about [how we want to deal](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10962/68872) with our tags [long term](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11199/68872).

Back to the point, there should definitely be a universe tag here. This would allow us to group the multiple series under one series so it's easier for experts to narrow down their search and find the specific universe they want, after which they can narrow it down further by series. The author tags should stick to our current usage as shown in the links in the title (used only for questions about the author).

#### For the universe tag  I suggest we use the tag [percy-jackson](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/percy-jackson) as it is the term it is best known as.

For the book series we should therefore rename the tag [percy-jackson-and-the-olympians](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/percy-jackson-and-the-olympians) (31 chars). We should continue to use the other series tags when they're required and the author tag for questions exclusively about the author.

Comment: I'll add some further reading in a bit.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on *what* this universe tag should be?

Comment: @Mithrandir All I know is the short googling I've done which I don't think entitles me to make a name for the universe.

Comment: @Mithrandir You probably know this universe better than most of us - is there a common fandom name for the universe or the collection of books as a whole?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - unfortunately, I'm not aware of any name that encompasses the whole thing right now. The *closest* is probably just 'Percy Jackson', and that's probably what the most people use to describe the series, but that often leads to people excluding e.g. *The Kane Chronicles*. I've also heard 'the Riordan universe', although that's less common. But I don't know of any name that the fandom uses to refer to the universe as a whole aside from those, unfortunately.

Comment: This whole time I thought *Percy Jackson* **was** the author

Comment: I've seen "Percy Jackson universe", "Riordan universe", and "Camp Halfblood universe" used online.  The main wiki is called "Riordan wiki".  I think whatever tag is chosen should include [tag:-universe].  e.g. [tag:percy-jackson-universe]